# Extracting Certificate and Private Key Files from a .pfx File

Tags: bash, openssl

I want to extract cert and private key from pfx file in a bash/powershell script by executing the 2 below cmds, but all they will require an input password, when I manually run the cmd, I just skip it by pressing the ‘Enter’, my question is how to skip it or autofill in the script.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in  KeyVaultcertificate.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out  server.crt
openssl pkcs12 -in KeyVaultcertificate.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem -nodes
```

[image]

Comment: The certificate is password protected. You need the password.  See passwd at following : https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl.html

Comment: The `openssl` command has an option to enter the password in the command line. Look it up. Off topic.